# XPatch set is empty. Why?

Tags: xml, shell

i have this script

```
echo "put in code"
read code
echo $(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency[code="$code"]/rate/text()' valiutos.xml)
```

If i put it in like that

```
$(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency[code="AUD"]/rate/text()' valiutos.xml)
```

it would print me the exchange rate of AUD that is written in my xml file, but if i want to put certain code from command line, it says : XPatch set is tempy.

How to fix? I am building a currency exchange program and i want user to type in currency code and see the rate

Comment: dont mind word "valiutos" , it's "rates" in english

Comment: Help huys! really stuck on this one

Comment: If you `echo 'code="$code"'` and `echo "code=\"$code\""` you might see what's going on....